# How do I represent negative char values in hexadecimal?

Tags: c, char, hex, signedness

The following code

```
char buffer[BSIZE];
...
if(buffer[0]==0xef)
...
```

Gives the compiler warning "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type".
The warning goes away when I change the check to

```
if(buffer[0]==0xffffffef)
```

This feels very counterintuitive. What is the correct way to check a `char` against a specific byte value in hex? (other than making it unsigned)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why `buffer[0] == 0xef` triggers a warning, and `buffer[0] == 0xffffffef` does not, you need to understand exactly what's happening in that expression.

Firstly, the `==` operator compares the *value* of two expressions, not the underlying representation - `0xef` is the number 239, and will only compare equal to that number; likewise `0xffffffef` is the number 4294967279 and will only compare equal to that.

There is no difference between the constants `0xef` and `239` in C: both have type `int` and the same value.  If your `char` has the range -128 to 127, then when you evaluate `buffer[0] == 0xef` the `buffer[0]` is promoted to `int`, which leaves its value unchanged.  It can therefore never compare equal to `0xef`, so the warning is correct.

However, there *is* potentially a difference between the constants `0xffffffef` and 4294967279; decimal constants are always signed, but hexadecimal constant may be unsigned.  On your system, it appears to have an unsigned type - probably `unsigned int` (because the value is too large to store in an `int`, but small enough to store in an `unsigned int`).  When you evaluate `buffer[0] == 0xffffffef`, the `buffer[0]` is promoted to `unsigned int`.  This leaves any positive value unchanged, but negative values are converted by adding `UINT_MAX + 1` to them; with a `char` that has range -128 to 127, the promoted values are in either of the ranges 0 to 127 or 4294967168 to 4294967295.  `0xffffffef` lies within this range, so it is possible for the comparison to return true.

---

If you are storing bit patterns rather than numbers, then you should be using `unsigned char` in the first place.  Alternatively, you may inspect the bit pattern of an object by casting a pointer to it to `unsigned char *`:

```
if (((unsigned char *)buffer)[0] == 0xef)
```

(This is obviously more conveniently done by using a separate variable of type `unsigned char *`).

As [PaulR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647100/how-do-i-represent-negative-char-values-in-hexadecimal/6647126#6647126) says, you can also use `buffer[0] == '\xef'` - this works because `'\xef'` is defined to be an `int` constant with the value that a `char` object with the bit pattern 0xef would have when converted to an int; eg. on a 2s complement system with signed chars, `'\xef'` is a constant with the value -17.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My code deals with strings and possibly an UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Nice explanation. Just to summarise, relationships between two compatible datums of differing lengths, are always performed within the context of the longest. Prior to evaluation, the shorter datum is converted to the longer type by sign/zero extension, in order to maintain its associated signed/unsigned range respectively.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with:

```
if (buffer[0] == '\xef')
```

?

Comment: That seems wrong - I'm guessing you may have tried `if (buffer == '\xef')` instead of `if (buffer[0] == '\xef')` ?

Comment: oops, I was tyring if(buffer[0] == "\xef")

Comment: This is a great answer -- buffer is an array of char, so you should be comparing it to a char.

Comment: I actually used this answer to solve my problem bu accepted the other one because of the detailed explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `buffer` contents are of type `char`. Making them `unsigned char` will work:

```
if ((unsigned char) (buffer[0]) == 0xef)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it just like with any other negative number:

```
if (buffer[0]== -0x6f)
```

But usually you want to use unsigned char as data type:

```
unsigned char buffer[BSIZE];
...
if(buffer[0]==0xef)
```

Reasons to use signed char are very rare. Even more rare are reasons to use "char without sign specification", which can be signed or unsigned on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

To spell out the reason explicitly: Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation defined. If your compiler treats `char` as signed by default then `0xef` will be larger than the largest possibled `signed char` (which is 127 or `0x7f`) and therefore your compare will always be false. Hence the warning.

Possible solutions are provided by the other answers.