# How to show special Chinese, Korean, Japanese characters without errors

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with show Chinese, Korean, Japanese characters. 
I'm using ID3Tag lib C++ to get metadata of some mp3 files. However, some file names are Korean characters, it shows wrong title name.
For example:

```
id3_utf16_t *tmp = id3_ucs4_utf16duplicate(id3_field_getstrings(f,0));
if (NULL != tmp)
{
     str.append(QString::fromUtf16(tmp));
     LOG << str;
}
```

The output of str is: `"³ª·Î ¸»ÇÒ °Í °°À¸¸é"`
but actually, the title name is: `"나로 말할 것 같으면"`

So how can show the special characters correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: There is no guarantee that ID3 tags are actually Unicode compatible. Can you show a hex dump of tmp?

Comment: I' using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: hex dump of tmp: b3 aa b7 ce

Comment: This doesn't look at all like the Korean string you have shown. How do you know it's this string?

Comment: In fact, it is title name of Korean music song.

Comment: OK I can understand that. The question is, how do you know it's name is written correctly there in the id3 tag? Do you have an independent way to read it?

Comment: The string you are seeing is a sequence of 8-bit characters interpreted as Latin-1, but in fact this sequence of bytes is your correct song title encoded in EUC-KR (not UTF16). [Proof](https://ideone.com/cVHBBs). So if you have an editor that is able to show EUC-KR, try to open your log file with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [website](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/latin_utf_base64_to_hex/latin_utf_base64_to_hex.php#text_hex_output) I took the output you pasted and converted it to hex. Then converted that to UTF-16LE. They are Korean characters after that point, but not exactly the ones you posted. I think Korean has a way of combining the characters that maybe this isn’t doing.

Edited to remove wrong answer

Comment: This is partly not an answer and partly a wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I have enough reputation to comment on the post, so I wasn’t sure how else to get clarity about the question. I can delete it if this is considered bad form.

Comment: More detail for LOG:
#define     LOG       qDebug()<<"["<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"]["<<__LINE__<<"]: "

Just output the function name, the line number and string

Comment: Using this [website](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/latin_utf_base64_to_hex/latin_utf_base64_to_hex.php#text_hex_output) I took the output you pasted and converted it to hex. Then converted that to UTF-16LE. They are Korean characters after that point, but not exactly the ones you posted. I think Korean has a way of combining the characters that maybe this isn’t doing.

Comment: It appears to be little endian. You need to look up the function for decoding from that format.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct if interpreted as an EUC-KR string.

```
# echo "³ª·Î ¸»ÇÒ °Í °°À¸¸é" | iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 | iconv -f EUC-KR -t utf8
나로 말할 것 같으면
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/cVHBBs)

So my educated guess as to what's happening is as follows:

1. The log file is encoded as EUC-KR (a 2-byte encoding).
2. You are looking at it with a tool (editor, terminal, whatever) that thinks it's Latin-1 (a 1-byte encoding).
3. Why is the log file encoded as EUC-KR? Because `tmp` is not in fact in UTF-16, it is in EUC-KR.

   ```
   # printf '\xb3\xaa\xb7\xce' | iconv -f EUC-KR -t utf-8
   나로
   ```

   `QString` cannot use `fromUtf16` to convert these bytes correctly.
4. Why is `tmp` in EUC-KR? I don't know. Perhaps the encoding in the text field is not set, or set incorrectly, so your library doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer.
I did it.
However, there is a new problem, how to detect encoding from the string.
It is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103294/c-how-to-inspect-file-byte-order-mark-in-order-to-get-if-it-is-utf-8. I'm reading it and trying to do
Thanks again

Comment: @Huong In general you cannot detect encoding, you can only guess it with more or less degree of uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you.
Could I ask you a favor? Please suggest me a web or a sample code to get high probability of encode. I'm stuck with it. Thanks